# Uniform norm on space of complex continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space.
Let $C(X)$ be the space of complex valued functions on $X$.
Let $||\cdot||$ be a norm which makes $C(X)$ a Banach space.
If $\lambda_x(f)=f(x)$ is bounded for $(C(X),||\cdot||)$ for each $x\in X$.
Prove that there exists positive constants $A$ and $B$ such that

$$
A||f||_\infty \leq ||f||\leq B||f||_\infty.
$$

I think that the first inequality holds from Banach-Steinhaus, 
but I can't see the second one, can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: What do you mean with $\lambda_x(f)=f(x)$ is bounded for $(C(X),\|\cdot\|)$? There are two ways: "for fixed $x$, the operator $\lambda_x$ is continuous" or  "$\sup\{\|\lambda_x(f)\|:x\in X\}<\infty$ for each $f\in C(X)$"

Comment: I mean the first one, I think that is the standard one. However, the second assertion follows from the first by Banach-Steinhaus.